# Time Stories Asylum - missing card 1

Tags: time-stories

Just got this game from a friend and card 1 that starts the Base card section is missing - does anyone have it? A screenshot or the the text would be great. Possibly it just says to read Base cards A to G from left to right but maybe it has other important info?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to it, you assumed correctly. Here's the card:

[image: card one front] [image: card one back]